# Why do I get a conflict if I execute this?

Tags: git

Given this Git tree:

[image]

***(same description, same commit)***

why Git produces a conflict if I execute this?

```
git checkout bugs
git rebase es-dev
```

I believed that if the same commit exists in two branches, when Git rebases one branch into other, simply ignores the commit in the branch being rebased. But it seems that's not the case, because `es-dev` contains exactly the same commits than `bugs` and I get a conflict. In this case I can just do a:

```
git checkout es-dev
git branch -D bugs
git checkout -b bugs
```

but in more complex cases it could be a problem... (i.e. if I have commits in `bugs` that don't exist in `master` or `es-dev`)

Comment: I am pretty sure that they don't contain *the same* commits. Please check their commit hashes, I am sure they differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branch `bugs` contains different commits than the branch `es-dev`. Otherwise, the graphic would look different.
The commits may contain the same changes, but the commit hashes are different making them different commits.

In your scenario, you can simply reset `bugs` to `es-dev`:

```
git branch -f bug es-dev
```

Comment: I've double checked and the hashes are the same. In fact, the commits in master come from a "git cherry-pick" from bugs and the 2 commits in es-dev come from a previous rebase the first two commits in bugs to the es branch. Then, is it possible that the problem is a bug my git release (1.5.1)?

Comment: @Ivan: Have you verified the commit hashes? A cherry-pick creates a *new* commit with the contents of the picked one. The same goes for a rebase. You say you double checked the hashes, yet I can't believe this. Can you "prove" that they are the same? Via a screenshot maybe?

Comment: Oppss, you are right... sorry, I don't kwow what I have double checked, but in the third check I've noticed that the hashes are different!!